# Add/remove form fields joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I create my own module with some form field.

[image]

How add/remove dynamicaly this form field?

For example, there are "Add button". I click on this button and form field add.

Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

this cannot be done in this section, as a module layout is a static template for the module. All of the fields are set when the xml file is read during module installation.
For set fields you can always use JavaScript to hide particular fields, but if you want to create,edit,delete or update information on multiple instances you will need a component. A nice easy to use component creator can be found here - http://joomlacomponentcreator.codelydia.com/